# Encoding error of watching sass files with gruntfiles and phpstorm

Tags: encoding, terminal, sass, gruntjs, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and a gruntfile.js to compile and watch my `.scss` files.

When I use the PhpStorm terminal to watch sass with `grunt watch` I get the error 
`(Line 70: Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC3")` for `//ééé`.

But when I use the Mac terminal to watch sass with `grunt watch` it's working well.

All files are in UTF-8 and I updated sass/compass to the last version.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I didn't find terminal encoding setting in PhpStorm.

Comment: Please can you check if running PhpStorm from terminal (`open  -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`) solves the problem?

Comment: please follow [IDEA-121713](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121713) for updates

Comment: This is not a PhpStorm specific bug. This is a bug on a deeper level, perhaps with the grunt tool, or command-line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your help by following your link I was able to solve the problem.

Opening PhpStorm with the terminal solve the problem but for a constant solution I edited `etc/profile` to add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` than I restarted PhpStorm and all local settings were on UTF8. (Checked with `$ locale`)